# Azure DevOps - CI Build randomly, auto starts and fails when no commits have been push to GitLab Repo/ Other Git?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gitlab, devops

We use Azure DevOps to connect gitlab make CI/CD in project.
When we enabled the setting "enabled Continuous Integration trigger", the pipeline will randomly start to CI and get fail, but actually no changes in the gitlab branch, no one to trigger it. it happend in every half hours, so weird.
That's the CI error code.

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: No references received in the response from https://git.xxxxgitlab.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack. Status: 429, Reason: Too Many Requests in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.ReadRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, HttpResponseMessage response) in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess) in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters) 在 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
`

Is anyone meet this question???

Comment: Reason: Too Many Requests in  please check any other request also coming same time.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 That error would have **nothing** to do with requests "coming [in at the] same time". It's a rate limiting error (see: [HTTP Status Code 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)). Azure DevOps is polling GitLab for changes periodically. It's happening often enough that it's triggering a rate limiting error.

Comment: @Daniel Mann Thanks for your answer. About 300 projects with that "continuous Integration trigger setting" met this problem, is there any good way can fix it?

Comment: oh, I have already get the answer. "rate limit" can be set in gitlab. [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rate_limits.html)